# Add URL to image using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd

I have some XSLT which im trying to add an URL against an image. So far i have

```
    <xsl:if test="$currentPage/ImageOne != ''"> 

      <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/ImageOne, 0)/*"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:attribute name="alt">
          <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/ImageOne"/>
        </xsl:attribute> 
      </xsl:element>

    </xsl:if>
```

If i add another XSLT node

```
      <xsl:attribute name="a">
          <xsl:value-of select="http://somesite.com"/>
        </xsl:attribute> 
      </xsl:element>
```

then i get a parser error (in the above code im using "a" in order to add a hyperlink to that image, but nothing works. COuld someone advise whats going wrong?

Thanks

New code

```
    <xsl:if test="$currentPage/ImageOne != ''"> 

        <xsl:element name="a"> 
        <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/ImageOne, 0)/*"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
          <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/ImageOne"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:element name="href">
          <xsl:value-of select="'http://www.microsoft.com'"/>
        </xsl:element>  
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: What parser error did you get?

Comment: Where are you adding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to add the fix url: `"http://somesite.com"` as value of the attribute `a`
and you use `xsl:value-of select` you have to put the "const" string into apostrophe (`'..'`)

Try:

```
  <xsl:attribute name="a">
          <xsl:value-of select="'http://somesite.com'"/>
        </xsl:attribute> 
      </xsl:element>
```

But also you do not need to to use `xsl:element` in your example:
The following may do as well:

```
<img a="http://somesite.com" alt="{$currentPage/ImageOne}">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/ImageOne, 0)/*"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

To have a link with an image try:

```
<a href="http://somesite.com" ">
 <img  alt="{$currentPage/ImageOne}">
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/ImageOne, 0)/*"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
   </img>
</a>
```

Comment: I changed the code since so i dont have the parser error any further.

I have changed the code (see above under New code) but i cant get it to work as expected (display and image which has a hyperlink to an external site)

Any further ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please consider at first how your html should look like at the end. At the moment you add a `href` attribute  to an `img`. Which doses not make  sense  at all. Try to move the href attribute above the img element.

Comment: Thanks. The code you posted didnt work. I dont know if this is due to me using Umbraco or not but i think i would need to follow the criteria under the "New Code" heading?